# symfony object image many to many

Tags: symfony

i have a database that need to have multiple image with an object.
in the list view, i see the multiple image but it appears in texte, i need to have image !!!

this is the list mapper of my product entity (one produc with many images)

```
 /**
 * @param ShowMapper $showMapper
 */
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)

{

    $showMapper
        ->with('PRODUCT DESCRIPTION', array('class' => 'col-md-7'))
        ->add('name')
        ->add('country')
        ->add('descriptionshortnat', null, array('label' => 'Description short (national)'))
        ->add('descriptionlongnat', null, array('label' => 'Description long (national)'))
        ->add('descriptionshorten', null, array('label' => 'Description short (english)'))
        ->add('descriptionlongen', null, array('label' => 'Description long (english)'))
        ->add('created')
        ->add('updated')
        ->end()

        ->with('PICTURES', array('class' => 'col-md-5'))
        ->add('image', 'string' , array("template"=>"AdminBundle::Admin/list_types/image.html.twig"))
        ->end()

        ->with('CLASSIFICATION', array('class' => 'col-md-5'))
        ->add('category')
        ->add('preservation', null, array('label' => 'Preservation method'))
        ->add('population', null, array('label' => 'Population target'))
        ->add('innovation')
        ->add('timeframe', null, array('label' => 'Comsumer timeframe'))
        ->add('component')
        ->end()
        ->with('PARTNERS', array('class' => 'col-md-5'))
        ->end()             
        ->with('COMPETITION', array('class' => 'col-md-5'))
        ->add('contact', 'sonata_type_model', array('required' => false, 'multiple' => true,'label' => 'Student team'))
        ->add('organisation', 'sonata_type_model', array('required' => false))
        ->add('competition', 'sonata_type_model', array('required' => false, 'multiple' => true))
        ->end()



    ;
}
```

}

And this is my twig for my 'image'

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    <a href="{{ asset('uploads/documents/') }}{{ value|nl2br }}"><img class="admin-list-preview" src="{{ asset('uploads/documents/') }}{{ value|nl2br }}"/></a>
{% endblock %}
```

and my class 'image'

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * Image
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var type
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * @var type
     */
    private $fichier;



    /**
     * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}


public function __toString()
{
return $this->fichier;    
}


public function getname()
{
return $this->fichier;
}




/**
 * Set fichier
 *
 * @param string $fichier
 *
 * @return Image
 */
public function setFichier($fichier)
{
    $this->fichier = $fichier;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fichier
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFichier()
{
    return $this->fichier;

}



/**
 * Set file
 *
 * @param string $file
 * @return Image
 */
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file=null)
{
    $this->file = $file;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get file
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}





public function upload() {
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if(null === $this->getFile())
    {
        return;
    }

    // we use the original file name here but you should
    // sanitize it at least to avoid any security issues

    // move takes the target directory and target filename as params
    $this->getFile()->move(
        $this->getUploadRootDir(),
        $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName()
    );

    // set the path property to the path where you've saved the file
    $this->setFichier($this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName());

    // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
    $this->setFile(null);






}



public function removeUpload() {
     if($file = $this->getAbsolutePath())
    {
        if(is_file($file))
        {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->getFichier()
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->getFichier();

}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->getFichier()
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getFichier();


}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded
    // documents should be saved
    return __DIR__.'/../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();

}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
    // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
    return 'uploads/documents';

  }
```

}

Thanks to help me on this,

i need to see my pictures (image) not the text !!!

doctrine yml of my enity (products)

```
AdminBundle\Entity\Products:
    type: entity
    table: null
    sortable: true
    repositoryClass: AdminBundle\Repository\ProductsRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        descriptionshortnat:
            type: text
            length: 500
            nullable: true
        descriptionlongnat:
            type: text
            length: 5000
            nullable: true
        descriptionshorten:
            type: text
            length: 500
            nullable: true
        descriptionlongen:
            type: text
            length: 5000
            nullable: true
        created:
            type: datetime
            nullable: true
            gedmo:
              timestampable:
                on: create
        updated:
            type: datetime
            nullable: true
            gedmo:
              timestampable:
                on: update
    lifecycleCallbacks:
      prePersist: [ setCreatedAtValue,setUpdatedAtValue ]
      preUpdate: [ setUpdatedAtValue ]
    manyToOne:
        country:
            targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Country
            joinColumn:
                name: country
                referencedColumnName: id
            nullable: TRUE
        category:
            targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Category
            joinColumn:
                name: category
                referencedColumnName: id
            nullable: TRUE
        preservation:
            targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Preservation
            joinColumn:
                name: preservation
                referencedColumnName: id
            nullable: TRUE
        population:
            targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Population
            joinColumn:
                name: population
                referencedColumnName: id
            nullable: TRUE
        innovation:
            targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Innovation
            joinColumn:
                name: innovation
                referencedColumnName: id
            nullable: TRUE
        timeframe:
            targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Timeframe
            joinColumn:
                name: timeframe
                referencedColumnName: id
            nullable: TRUE
        component:
            targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Component
            joinColumn:
                name: component
                referencedColumnName: id
            nullable: TRUE
    manyToMany:
        contact:
            targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Contact
            joinTable:
                name: allproducts
                joinColumns:
                    products:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    contact:
                        referencedColumnName: id
        organisation:
            targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Organisation
            joinTable:
                name: allorganisation
                joinColumns:
                    product:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    organisation:
                        referencedColumnName: id
        competition:
            targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Competition
            joinTable:
                name: allcompetition
                joinColumns:
                    competition:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    product:
                        referencedColumnName: id
        image:
            targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Image
            joinTable:
                name: allpictures
                joinColumns:
                    product:
                        referencedColumnName: id
                inverseJoinColumns:
                    image:
                        referencedColumnName: id
```

dump value

[SCREEN SHOT OF THE DUMP()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quZa2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wont see you image - use this construction:

```
{{ asset('uploads/documents/' ~ object.image ) }}
uploads/documents/ - folder to you directory with images.
object.image - image name (twig variable)
```

Example with SonataAdminBundle

```
{% for image in object.image %} 
     <img class="admin-list-preview" src="{{ asset('uploads/documents/' ~ image) }}"/> 
{% end for %}
```

Comment: Thanks, i try this but it give me this message error :       An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string") in AdminBundle::Admin/list_types/image.html.twig at line 3.

Comment: template AdminBundle::Admin/list_types/image.html.twig

Comment: {% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}
{% block field %}
    <img class="admin-list-preview" src="{{ asset('uploads/documents/' ~ object.image) }}"/>
{% endblock %}

Comment: the object you try to display is a collection, so you have to loop to have all the elements in it. can you dump it ?

Comment: ok, so first : What do you have now and what do you want.
- second : do you really have files uploaded on you server ?
- you can dump you image object in you view with dump()

Comment: in you template you can use twid function {{ dump() }}, then browser show you all values.

Comment: actually, i can download image with product entity with a relation many to many to add pictures. it works. i have the name of the pictures on the serveur and if i go to the entity of my image, i see my pictures. the problem is that i want to see the image and not the name of the object in the list view of my 'product' entity

Comment: i try dump() in my twig file, but it appears only text description,etc...

Comment: it's up in the page: SCREEN SHOT OF THE DUMP() click on it

Comment: if i do this: {% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    <img class="admin-list-preview" src="{{ asset('uploads/documents/' ~ dump()) }}"/>
{% endblock %}

Comment: i have a frame without pictures ??

Comment: Try this
`{% for image in object.image %}  
<img class="admin-list-preview" src="{{ asset('uploads/documents/' ~ image) }}"/>
{% end for %}`

Comment: sorry, can you give me all the code to put in the twig view, i don't want to make a mystake

Comment: this is the solution i told you an hour ago ... a simple loop

Comment: What i have to do, if i want to have a loop with a thumbmail 'object'

Comment: @oliviertoppin On SO we expects to have one question at a time. So you should accept this answer and make another question about "thumbnail image".

Comment: @oliviertoppin and remember to accept all useful answers in your past questions ;-)

Comment: @oliviertoppin On maxim answer there is an accept flag just under the downvote arrow.